# Problem with statsmodels when importing plotnine and other moduels

Tags: python, statsmodels, plotnine

I'm having a problem importing the modules `plotnine` and `binsreg`. When I try to import them I get the error

`ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from 'statsmodels._version' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/_version.py)`

I don't have a problem importing statsmodels itself (e.g. `import statsmodels as sm` runs fine), or anything else from it, but the line `from statsmodels._version import __version__, __version_tuple__` yields an error. That file itself just contains

```
# coding: utf-8
# file generated by setuptools_scm
# don't change, don't track in version control
__version__ = version = '0.13.5'
__version_tuple__ = version_tuple = (0, 13, 5)
```

I tried uninstalling and re-installing statsmodels and I tried doing that in python 3.8.5 and python 3.9.10. I don't usually work in python so perhaps I have overlooked something obvious? Any ideas?

Comment: it seems that you have a file which have the same name which is in package in the root directory, change file names in root directory and try again

Comment: do you mean another installation of statsmodels somewhere on the path? I'm not quite following. There isn't a file with a similar name in the root of the project.

Comment: Can you provide the versions of each package? (binsreg, plotnine, statsmodels) I'm unable to reproduce using binsreg==1.0.0, plotnine==0.10.1, and statsmodels==0.13.5.